# Very slow INSERT using InnoDB with unique key

Tags: mysql, innodb

I'm getting very slow inserts, about 40ms each, on small InnoDB tables, for this table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS events (
    serial          INT NOT NULL,               -- client side serial number
    time            BIGINT NOT NULL,            -- UNIX timestamp, client side, not server side
    shard           VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,      -- server shard
    owner_name      VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,      -- name of owner
    object_name     VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,      -- object name
    region_name     VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,      -- name of region
    region_corner_x   INT NOT NULL,             -- corner of region
    region_corner_Y   INT NOT NULL,             -- corner of region
    local_position_x  FLOAT NOT NULL,           -- X and Y only
    local_position_y  FLOAT NOT NULL,           -- X and Y only
    tripid          CHAR(40) NOT NULL,          -- trip ID (random unique identifier)
    severity        TINYINT NOT NULL,           -- an enum, really
    eventtype       VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,       -- STARTUP, SHUTDOWN, etc.
    msg             TEXT,                       -- human-readable message
    auxval          FLOAT NOT NULL,             -- some other value associated with the event type
    INDEX(tripid),
    UNIQUE INDEX(tripid, serial),               -- catch dups at insert time
    INDEX(eventtype)
) ENGINE InnoDB;
```

EXPLAIN on an INSERT gives me

```
Explain EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON INSERT INTO events  (time, shard, owner_name, object_name, region_name, region_corner_x, region_corner_y, local_position_x, local_position_y, tripid, severity, eventtype, msg, auxval, serial)  VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?): 
Explain: {
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "table": {
      "insert": true,
      "table_name": "events",
      "access_type": "ALL"
    }
  }
}
DB update time: 58.120396ms
```

I tried removing the indices. No speedup. Tried starting from an empty table. No speedup.  This was inside a transaction, so I cut down the transaction to just this insert. No speedup.

It's a tiny test case. 200 records. Empty tables. Idle test machine. That time is for one INSERT.  200 inserts take about 10 seconds.  (The inserts have to be done individually; I'm simulating incoming events here, not bulk loading.)

Now if I switch to MyISAM, things speed up by a factor of about 200!

DB update time: 108.224µs

Time for the whole test drops from 10 seconds to 0.181 second.

I know InnoDB is slower, but 200x?

Using MySQL 5.7.21-0ubuntu0.16.04.1. System is a 4-CPU Linux desktop with a rotating hard drive.

Comment: What's the characterset of this table? InnoDB wouldn't be that slow. And I'll test it with your DDL.

Comment: Can you post your test code, and some other details? I did my test with your table and SQL, it only takes 0.047s in a new table.

Comment: Consider changing this option https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit

Comment: How big is the value of `msg`?

Comment: "msg" is 0-100 bytes.

Comment: Character set is utf8mb4.

Comment: Flush-related variables:
    binlog_max_flush_queue_time    | 0   
    flush                          | OFF  
    flush_time                     | 0    
    innodb_adaptive_flushing       | ON    
    innodb_adaptive_flushing_lwm   | 10    
    innodb_flush_log_at_timeout    | 1     
    innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit | 1     
    innodb_flush_method            |       
    innodb_flush_neighbors         | 1     
    innodb_flush_sync              | ON    
    innodb_flushing_avg_loops      | 30

Comment: Code is at "https://github.com/John-Nagle/vehiclelogserver". It's in Go. It can be run with "go test" if you create the database and tables using the .sql file, and create a "~/keys/vehicledbconf.json" directory  with something like { "mysql": { "database" : "vehicles", "user" : "USERNAME", "password" : "PASS" }, "authkey": {"MAR2018": "SOMEJUNKVALUE"},}